# Php/MySQL Auto date checking/comparing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, compare

Wanted to ask You how can I setup something on my php website, that would everyday automatically check and compare current date to all the database datetime entries and delete the rows of the dates that are in the past (for ex. if the current date is 2014-03-17, it would delete the rows that have datetime of 2014-03-16 ).
Because I basically have a TV-package website (not a real thing, just for a class), where you can order a package, you enter for how long and it adds that amount to current date, writes the order into database with the date written into a field named "expires". Would it make sense if I just wrote the checking function into the index, so when someone visits the site it would delete it? If so, how could I compare the two dates?
The DB example looks something like this: http://s29.postimg.org/7sbgj2hnr/dbtest.png

Comment: Cron Job or Scheduled Task would probably work

Comment: Don't really know anything about those, is it possible to do without any external plugins etc.? Maybe just putting the check into every single page load would work?

Comment: Those aren't external plugins, they are schedulers built into their respective OS. Sure you can check on every single page load but what happens if you do not load your page for a few days? You can look into a [MySQL-based Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html) as well

Comment: Basically it's not even a real thing, it's just for a one-time show, that's why I don't really need/want anything running on the OS side. If I was to put the check into every single page though, how can I compare the current date to the datetime in the picture?

Comment: Just use `$sql = "DELETE FROM tableName WHERE \`expires\`>'".date('Y-m-d')."'";`

Comment: BTW you will look a lot more impressive if you learn scheduled tasks either within the OS or DB...

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with your code, just had to switch ">" to "<". Would you happen to know how could I schedule the check using MySql though? P.s. You used comments instead of an 'answer' so I cannot check it as answered :(

Comment: I just noticed there's an option of "Event" on Navicat, it gave me this template: "CREATE EVENT `NewEvent`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
;" Maybe I could just put in your code in here and it would automatically do it every 10 minutes?

Comment: My bad, finger slipped on `>`. Anyways, I linked you to a MySQL resource which should help you out. Unfortunately, I've never used Navicat before :/ so there's no harm in having you try it out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I highly recommend a scheduled task, you can do it in PHP by calling:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tableName WHERE `expires`<'".date('Y-m-d')."'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the date to a unix timestamp and compare it against the value of time() like you would any other integers.